# VSTO Word Interop project setup into an existing project

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, office-interop, office-addins

I Have an existing project which I want to create a word document from. I have added the new Word ThisDocument project into my existing solution and added a reference to it into my existing project.

I am trying to create an instance of the class inside my existing project like this:

```
WordEditor.ThisDocument doc = new WordEditor.ThisDocument();
```

The error I am getting:

There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'factory' of ThisDocument.ThisDocument(Factory, IServiceProvider)

The constructor:

```
public ThisDocument(global::Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Factory factory, global::System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : 
                base(factory, serviceProvider, "ThisDocument", "ThisDocument") {
            Globals.Factory = factory;
        }
```

I understand that I need to pass these two parameters but how do I get access to them in my existing project?

Comment: Do you need to automate Word from your standalone application? What exactly are you going to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

For all Office apps, Word included, the only creatable object is `Application` - `Word.Application` in case of Word. But in case of VSTO addins, `Application` object is already available through `Globals.ThisAddin.Application`.

If you need to create a new document, do not use `new` operator - use `Application.Documents.Add`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add a new document the Word object model provides the [Documents.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.documents.add) method which returns a `Document` object that represents a new, empty document added to the collection of open documents. The name of the template to be used for the new document can be passed as a parameter. If this argument is omitted, the `Normal` template is used.

There is no need to add a reference to the VSTO project if you need to automate MS Word from your standalone application. See [How to automate Microsoft Word to create a new document by using Visual C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-word-create-file-using-visual-c) for more information on that.